# Magic keyboard keyboard convert

Tags: keyboard

I have a problem with my magic keyboard
I bought an ISO (Swiss) version keyboard by mistake so that 
 it has a vertical return key, and an extra key next to Y.
but I prefer the ANSI arrangement 
 So I want to use $ for basic enter and >< key for a basic shift

Do you know the answer?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried editing the keyboard using System Preferences?

Comment: Karabiner might be able to do what you want.